# How I can change column view (org-mode, agenda) - default settings

Tags: org-mode

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(
    ("1" "TODAY" agenda "" (
        (org-agenda-ndays 1)
        (org-agenda-use-time-grid nil)
        (org-agenda-overriding-columns-format "%TODO %7EFFORT %PRIORITY %100ITEM 100%TAGS")
        (org-agenda-view-columns-initially t)))
    ("2" "TODO" todo "TODO"(
        (org-agenda-files '("/Users/inbox.org"))
        (todo "NEXT")))
    ("3" "DONE" todo "DONE")...
```

In the first filter (1 = TODAY), I have following function:

```
org-agenda-overriding-columns-format...
```

How can I add this function for all my filters (2, 3) and create this as default?

Answer (score 1):

Set the variable in your .emacs (or other initialization file):

```
(setq org-agenda-overriding-columns-format "%TODO %7EFFORT %PRIORITY     %100ITEM 100%TAGS")
```

BTW, `org-agenda-overriding-columns-format` is a variable, not a function.

Comment: There is a tutorial on Worg: [Emacs Org's Column View - orgmode.org](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-column-view-tutorial.html), hope this may help someone see this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the column widths by customizing the `org-columns-default-format` variable. So:

`M-x customize variable org-columns-default-format`

There, you can change the number in front of each column name to the character width you want. For example, if you want the ITEM column to be 50 characters wide, change `%25ITEM` to `%50ITEM`.

And if a column doesn't have a numeric value after the percent sign, you can add one.

Hope that helps.